# How to stop further JavaScript events from executing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, infragistics

I'm using an Infragistics grid on a form and am handling multiple client-side events on the cells (e.g. cell click, before cell edit, before cell update, etc).

On the cell click event, I'm spawning a secondary window (successfully) as follows:

```
var convChartWindow = window.open("conversioncharts/" + currentCell.getValue() + ".html", "chart", "location=0,0, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=" + screen.width + ", height=175");        
convChartWindow.focus();
```

However, the `convChartWindow` does not maintain the focus, and gets covered with the parent window. None of my other cell events fire after this, but there seems to be some Infragistics JavaScript that runs.

Is there a something I can put after the `.focus()` above to prevent further JavaScript from running and keep the focus on the correct window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what infragistics is. ill assume its some framework over which you have no control. if i were you i would try the following:

1) set a timeout to take focus back to the window after 1000 ms, or set a timeout loop to set focus to the window you need. this is a hack.

2) figure out what functions fire the events that ruin your life, override those functions in your code and add a flag that will prevent them from doing something evil

3) last, atleast read this:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html
there might be something useful for you in there

Answer (score 4):

Call this:

```
// Prevents event bubble up or any usage after this is called.
// pE - event object
function StopEvent(pE)
{
   if (!pE)
     if (window.event)
       pE = window.event;
     else
       return;
  if (pE.cancelBubble != null)
     pE.cancelBubble = true;
  if (pE.stopPropagation)
     pE.stopPropagation();
  if (pE.preventDefault)
     pE.preventDefault();
  if (window.event)
     pE.returnValue = false;
  if (pE.cancel != null)
     pE.cancel = true;
}  // StopEvent
```

This was snipped from here: [What is equivalent of 'event.returnValue=false' in Firefox](http://forums.asp.net/t/1071858.aspx)

and was written by Peter Blum
See: [PeterBlum.com](http://www.peterblum.com/Home.aspx)

Comment: What is the 'pE'/event object that gets sent into this function?

Comment: Try passing in this. i.e. StopEvent(this);
Otherwise what are the parameters of your Javascript event?

Comment: That didn't work. It runs through the code, but doesn't stop the focus changing back. The parameters of the event are just strings of IDs.

Comment: Are there any polling or timeout Javascript functions on your page?

Comment: Nope. None that I've written. That said, the Infragistics JavaScript might, but I'm not sure why it would.

Answer (score 0):

Have the child window call the focus itself when it opens.

Answer (score 0):

If there is something else in the function that runs the code you gave, try using:

```
break;
```

after:

```
convChartWindow.focus();
```

Comment: break is for exiting a loop